# adding explode time in php

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a table services the fields are  Proc_ID, Proc_No, Proc_Services, Proc_time,and Proc_Price. I want to add all the Procedure time(Proc_Time) of services.

**Here is the code**

```
If
00:15:00

00:30:00
```

The answer is 00:45:00.. but my code got a wrong answer. if the start time is 9:00 am hour and services 1 has a 00:15:00 and services 2 is 00:30:00 the reservation end will be 9:45.

```
$dt = $_POST['restime'];
$p1 = $_POST['dermaproc'];

$tmp = "";

foreach ($p1 as $key) {
    $tmp .= $key;
}

$today = strtotime("TODAY");

 $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM services WHERE Proc_ID = '$tmp' ";
 $res3 = $conx->query($sql3);
 $row3 = $res3->fetch_assoc();

      $explode = explode(",", $tmp); 
      foreach ($explode as $key1) {

 $sql4 = "SELECT Proc_Time FROM services WHERE Proc_ID = '$key1'";

      $res4 = $conx->query($sql4);
      $row4 = $res4->fetch_assoc();
      $pt = $row4['Proc_Time'];
      $m_time1 = strtotime($dt) - $today;
      $m_time2 = strtotime($pt) - $today;
      $m_total = $m_time1 + $m_time2 + $today;
      $etime = date('h:i:s', $m_total);

      echo    $etime;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add up all of the times for each procedure and then add this to the start time, so this loops round each procedure (I'm assuming that `$_POST['dermaproc']` contains a list of the procedures), it just adds up the times for each procedure in the loop.  After the loop it adds the total time to the appointment start time.

```
$dt = $_POST['restime'];
$p1 = $_POST['dermaproc'];
$today = strtotime("TODAY");

$m_total = 0;
foreach ($p1 as $key1) {
    $sql4 = "SELECT Proc_Time FROM services WHERE Proc_ID = '$key1'";
    $res4 = $conx->query($sql4);
    $row4 = $res4->fetch_assoc();
    $m_total += strtotime($row4['Proc_Time']) - $today;
}
$etime = date('H:i:s', $m_total+strtotime($dt));

echo     $etime;
```

Comment: thankyou so much, but what if I want answer  is 24 hours format. 12:00:00 is the start date and plus 01:00:00 is equal to 13:00:00. Please reply. Thanks

Comment: All you need to do is to change the format of the date to `'H:i:s'` - updated the answer.